# How to conditionally instantiate a bean in xml config?

Tags: xml, spring-boot

```
<bean id="profListener" class="listner.ProfListener"/>
```

profiles are prod,qaod and jc
activekc is another property I read from the yml file.

Ideally I want to do something like 
if profile.contains(activekc) 
then instantiate that bean
or just run without transferring the control to the listener.

The xml config file has other beans I want all the profiles to instantiate. So I need a condition for this particular bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `profile` attribute of the main `beans` tag. So you'd potentially have a separate context xml for each profile.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd"
  profile="prod,qaod">

 <bean id="profListener" class="listner.ProfListener"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: I want my jc profile to not enter the listener but read this bean. Is That possible?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you mean you want the bean to exist but not do anything? For that you could create another implementation of the interface and declare it in a `<beans>` declaration that is for the jc profile only.

Comment: I have a parameter that my spring boot reads and saves into the string activekc. This can be changed dynamically so I need this condition - if profile.contains(activekc) then instantiate this bean else do not instantiate. Now, my questions is how do I achieve that comparison in xml file.